# How to show that a set of terms within a sequence is finite?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose a sequence converges to a limit $x$, given another value $y$ with $x < y$, I am trying to prove that a set $\{a_n : a_n > y\}$ is finite.

I am starting from the definition of a limit, which tells me that:

$$\forall \epsilon \, \exists N \ \text{ such that } n > N \implies |a_n - x| < \epsilon$$

My thought then is to show that if $\epsilon = y - x$, I have then know for some $N$, $n>N$ gives:

$$|x_n - x| < y - x$$

$$|x_n| < y$$

But I'm not sure if that is helpful to my proof.

I am stuck because I have not been able to convince myself that the set is finite.

Any help with understanding or a better approach would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the right idea, I'll finish it for you.

Let $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}a_n = L$ and let $M > L$. We wish to prove that the set
$$A=\{a_n \mid a_n>M\}$$
is finite. Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $|A|=\infty$. Let $\varepsilon = M - L > 0$. There exists an integer $N$ such that if $n \ge N$, then
$$|a_n - L| < M -L.$$
Since $|A|=\infty$, there exists an integer $m$ such that $a_m \in A$ and $m \ge N$. Thus,
$$|a_m - L| = a_m -L< M-L \implies a_m <M,$$
which contradicts the fact that $a_m \in A$. Therefore, $A$ is finite.